# Data not saved when device is turned off

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7

I am using Core Data to store data in a simple app using a simple table structure. Table rows are dynamically created. The data in the newly created row come from the input of a detail view controller. The row gets created nicely and the data is persistent when I shut down the app or turn the device off and on.

The issue rears its ugly head when I update the detail view and therefor the row. The data changes that are made persist when the app is shut down and brought back up again.

However, when I turn the device off and then back on the originally created row and its data persists but the changes that were made are gone.

I'm using `iOS SDK 7.1` and `Xcode 5.1.1`. Is anyone familiar with this scenario?

Comment: Seems to me that you are not persisting the updates. Consider including code to call `save` on the `NSManagedObjectContext` following any action by the user to update details.

Comment: Where do you call the context saving? I expect when you turn off the device the method is not called? Have you tried to debug?